Problema ao usar perfil persistente com Playwright (Java) no Chromium para carregar o Web PKI
Olá, pessoal. Estou desenvolvendo uma automação para um site do governo do estado do Ceará que exige o uso de um componente chamado Web PKI. Esse componente é responsável por carregar os certificados digitais instalados no computador para autenticação.
Estou usando as seguintes tecnologias: Java, Spring, Playwright, e o Chromium para a navegação.
Contexto:
Criei manualmente um perfil no Chromium e instalei o componente Web PKI neste perfil. Para abrir o navegador com esse perfil manualmente, utilizo o seguinte comando no terminal, e funciona perfeitamente (o Web PKI está presente):
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-1148\chrome-win\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\USER\PerfilAutomacaoPlayWright" --new-window
Em seguida, configurei o Playwright para usar este perfil com o código abaixo:
// Diretório do perfil personalizado
Path userDataDir = Path.of("C:\Users\USER\PerfilAutomacaoPlayWright");
// Configurações para iniciar o navegador com o perfil persistente
BrowserContext context = playwright.chromium().launchPersistentContext(
userDataDir,
new BrowserType.LaunchPersistentContextOptions()
.setHeadless(false) // Inicia o navegador visível
);
Problema:
Quando o Playwright inicia o Chromium, ele não usa o perfil configurado no diretório C:\Users\USER\PerfilAutomacaoPlayWright. Em vez disso:

Ele parece criar ou usar um outro perfil (diferente do configurado).

O Web PKI não está presente no navegador iniciado pelo Playwright.


O comportamento esperado seria que o Playwright abrisse o navegador exatamente com o perfil persistente configurado, já com o Web PKI instalado e funcionando.
O que já tentei:
Verifiquei se o diretório do perfil contém a subpasta Default, e tudo está conforme esperado.
Testei abrir o Chromium manualmente com o mesmo diretório, e o Web PKI está presente.
Configurei o navegador para não ser executado no modo headless (para verificar visualmente).
Minhas dúvidas:
Por que o Playwright não utiliza o perfil persistente configurado no userDataDir?
Existe algo que preciso ajustar para que o perfil com o Web PKI funcione corretamente com o Playwright?
Como posso depurar e garantir que o navegador iniciado pelo Playwright esteja realmente carregando o perfil correto?
Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!
